# Can I hide my master degree permanently?

Tags: mathematics

I am doing an undergraduate masters (4 year course) in Cambridge and end up having a first class honour in the BA and upper second class in the Mxxx. I have emailed the uni to abandon my fourth year result but seems that it is too late to withdraw. Can I just destroy the degree letter and hide my Master degree?

Comment: I don't understand - what is the intent of this?

Comment: Try and get a little perspective. A 2:1 is **not** a poor grade- especially not in a Master's degree from Cambridge.

Comment: I second @astronat's comment -- speaking as someone with a 2:1 in the BA and a "merit" (=low-ish first) in Part III. Obviously it depends what jobs or further courses you intend to apply for, but my advice would be: if you are asked for your degree classification, give it honestly; if you are not asked for it, you may or may not wish to include it.

Comment: I'm still unsure of the intent of the OP - I'm speaking as an American student.

Comment: My understanding is that a four-year undergraduate master's degree is just that: You do one (combined) degree and get the Mxxx; you don't come out after four years with a BA *and* an Mxxx. Accordingly, unless you manage to withdraw after three years, there is no BA to fall back on and your Mxxx is your only degree (and thus your only degree grade).

Comment: @owjburnham I'm not sure Part III works like that: https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/postgrad/mathiii although http://www.camdata.admin.cam.ac.uk/structure-undergraduate-courses-cambridge#graduate seems to suggest that there *is* no overall degree classification (which was news to me)

Answer (score 2):

Hide it from whom? The only scenario I can see is that you want to omit it from your CV. But if you do that, how are you going to explain the one year gap?

It's also worth noting that you didn't get "*a first class honour in the BA*". You may have got first class honours in one or more years of the Tripos, but your degree certificate will say merely that on a certain date, in a congregation holden (sic) in the Senate House, you were admitted to the degree of Bachelor of Arts. Not that my employers have asked to see the certificate.

Finally, "*permanently*"? Don't make rash decisions which you might regret. In two years you'll be able to graduate MA and that (in Cambridge terms, at least) is a higher degree than the MMath/MEng/etc. You can put *MA (Cantab)* as your postnominal letters on your CV and hide the Mxxx that way, although it will still make sense to mention it as an explanation for what you were doing this past year.